# how to sync android contacts with firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-syncadapter, android-database

I am new to android programming and I am Developing an App in which the user has an account in firebase and he wants to sync his/her mobile phone contacts with the firebase database contacts. One way is to get all the firebase contacts and compare with the user phone contacts and filter out the similar contacts and update the view.....But this Logic is absured, when the firebase database increases i.e. hit million users!

Please Help me....or at least give me right direction in which I Should Start working!

thanx in advance

My database Tree

```
-Users
   |
   ----959670000
   |      |
   |      ------name
   |
   + ----750890000
   +------859200000
```

Here Is How My dataBase tree looks Like How Should I save

Answer (score 3):

In order to be as universal as possible, you can create a class with the prefix of all countries.

```
public class CountryToPhonePrefix {
    public static String getPhone(String code) {
        return country2phone.get(code.toUpperCase());
    }
    public static Map<String, String> getAll(){
        return country2phone;
    }
    private static Map<String, String> country2phone = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        country2phone.put("AF", "+93");
        country2phone.put("AL", "+355");
        country2phone.put("DZ", "+213");
        country2phone.put("AD", "+376");
        country2phone.put("AO", "+244");
        country2phone.put("AG", "+1-268");
        country2phone.put("AR", "+54");
        country2phone.put("AM", "+374");
        country2phone.put("AU", "+61");
        country2phone.put("AT", "+43");
        country2phone.put("AZ", "+994");
        country2phone.put("BS", "+1-242");
        country2phone.put("BH", "+973");
        country2phone.put("BD", "+880");
        country2phone.put("BB", "+1-246");
        country2phone.put("BY", "+375");
        country2phone.put("BE", "+32");
        country2phone.put("BZ", "+501");
        country2phone.put("BJ", "+229");
        country2phone.put("BT", "+975");
        country2phone.put("BO", "+591");
        country2phone.put("BA", "+387");
        country2phone.put("BW", "+267");
        country2phone.put("BR", "+55");
        country2phone.put("BN", "+673");
        country2phone.put("BG", "+359");
        country2phone.put("BF", "+226");
        country2phone.put("BI", "+257");
        country2phone.put("KH", "+855");
        country2phone.put("CM", "+237");
        country2phone.put("CA", "+1");
        country2phone.put("CV", "+238");
        country2phone.put("CF", "+236");
        country2phone.put("TD", "+235");
        country2phone.put("CL", "+56");
        country2phone.put("CN", "+86");
        country2phone.put("CO", "+57");
        country2phone.put("KM", "+269");
        country2phone.put("CD", "+243");
        country2phone.put("CG", "+242");
        country2phone.put("CR", "+506");
        country2phone.put("CI", "+225");
        country2phone.put("HR", "+385");
        country2phone.put("CU", "+53");
        country2phone.put("CY", "+357");
        country2phone.put("CZ", "+420");
        country2phone.put("DK", "+45");
        country2phone.put("DJ", "+253");
        country2phone.put("DM", "+1-767");
        country2phone.put("DO", "+1-809and1-829");
        country2phone.put("EC", "+593");
        country2phone.put("EG", "+20");
        country2phone.put("SV", "+503");
        country2phone.put("GQ", "+240");
        country2phone.put("ER", "+291");
        country2phone.put("EE", "+372");
        country2phone.put("ET", "+251");
        country2phone.put("FJ", "+679");
        country2phone.put("FI", "+358");
        country2phone.put("FR", "+33");
        country2phone.put("GA", "+241");
        country2phone.put("GM", "+220");
        country2phone.put("GE", "+995");
        country2phone.put("DE", "+49");
        country2phone.put("GH", "+233");
        country2phone.put("GR", "+30");
        country2phone.put("GD", "+1-473");
        country2phone.put("GT", "+502");
        country2phone.put("GN", "+224");
        country2phone.put("GW", "+245");
        country2phone.put("GY", "+592");
        country2phone.put("HT", "+509");
        country2phone.put("HN", "+504");
        country2phone.put("HU", "+36");
        country2phone.put("IS", "+354");
        country2phone.put("IN", "+91");
        country2phone.put("ID", "+62");
        country2phone.put("IR", "+98");
        country2phone.put("IQ", "+964");
        country2phone.put("IE", "+353");
        country2phone.put("IL", "+972");
        country2phone.put("IT", "+39");
        country2phone.put("JM", "+1-876");
        country2phone.put("JP", "+81");
        country2phone.put("JO", "+962");
        country2phone.put("KZ", "+7");
        country2phone.put("KE", "+254");
        country2phone.put("KI", "+686");
        country2phone.put("KP", "+850");
        country2phone.put("KR", "+82");
        country2phone.put("KW", "+965");
        country2phone.put("KG", "+996");
        country2phone.put("LA", "+856");
        country2phone.put("LV", "+371");
        country2phone.put("LB", "+961");
        country2phone.put("LS", "+266");
        country2phone.put("LR", "+231");
        country2phone.put("LY", "+218");
        country2phone.put("LI", "+423");
        country2phone.put("LT", "+370");
        country2phone.put("LU", "+352");
        country2phone.put("MK", "+389");
        country2phone.put("MG", "+261");
        country2phone.put("MW", "+265");
        country2phone.put("MY", "+60");
        country2phone.put("MV", "+960");
        country2phone.put("ML", "+223");
        country2phone.put("MT", "+356");
        country2phone.put("MH", "+692");
        country2phone.put("MR", "+222");
        country2phone.put("MU", "+230");
        country2phone.put("MX", "+52");
        country2phone.put("FM", "+691");
        country2phone.put("MD", "+373");
        country2phone.put("MC", "+377");
        country2phone.put("MN", "+976");
        country2phone.put("ME", "+382");
        country2phone.put("MA", "+212");
        country2phone.put("MZ", "+258");
        country2phone.put("MM", "+95");
        country2phone.put("NA", "+264");
        country2phone.put("NR", "+674");
        country2phone.put("NP", "+977");
        country2phone.put("NL", "+31");
        country2phone.put("NZ", "+64");
        country2phone.put("NI", "+505");
        country2phone.put("NE", "+227");
        country2phone.put("NG", "+234");
        country2phone.put("NO", "+47");
        country2phone.put("OM", "+968");
        country2phone.put("PK", "+92");
        country2phone.put("PW", "+680");
        country2phone.put("PA", "+507");
        country2phone.put("PG", "+675");
        country2phone.put("PY", "+595");
        country2phone.put("PE", "+51");
        country2phone.put("PH", "+63");
        country2phone.put("PL", "+48");
        country2phone.put("PT", "+351");
        country2phone.put("QA", "+974");
        country2phone.put("RO", "+40");
        country2phone.put("RU", "+7");
        country2phone.put("RW", "+250");
        country2phone.put("KN", "+1-869");
        country2phone.put("LC", "+1-758");
        country2phone.put("VC", "+1-784");
        country2phone.put("WS", "+685");
        country2phone.put("SM", "+378");
        country2phone.put("ST", "+239");
        country2phone.put("SA", "+966");
        country2phone.put("SN", "+221");
        country2phone.put("RS", "+381");
        country2phone.put("SC", "+248");
        country2phone.put("SL", "+232");
        country2phone.put("SG", "+65");
        country2phone.put("SK", "+421");
        country2phone.put("SI", "+386");
        country2phone.put("SB", "+677");
        country2phone.put("SO", "+252");
        country2phone.put("ZA", "+27");
        country2phone.put("ES", "+34");
        country2phone.put("LK", "+94");
        country2phone.put("SD", "+249");
        country2phone.put("SR", "+597");
        country2phone.put("SZ", "+268");
        country2phone.put("SE", "+46");
        country2phone.put("CH", "+41");
        country2phone.put("SY", "+963");
        country2phone.put("TJ", "+992");
        country2phone.put("TZ", "+255");
        country2phone.put("TH", "+66");
        country2phone.put("TL", "+670");
        country2phone.put("TG", "+228");
        country2phone.put("TO", "+676");
        country2phone.put("TT", "+1-868");
        country2phone.put("TN", "+216");
        country2phone.put("TR", "+90");
        country2phone.put("TM", "+993");
        country2phone.put("TV", "+688");
        country2phone.put("UG", "+256");
        country2phone.put("UA", "+380");
        country2phone.put("AE", "+971");
        country2phone.put("GB", "+44");
        country2phone.put("US", "+1");
        country2phone.put("UY", "+598");
        country2phone.put("UZ", "+998");
        country2phone.put("VU", "+678");
        country2phone.put("VA", "+379");
        country2phone.put("VE", "+58");
        country2phone.put("VN", "+84");
        country2phone.put("YE", "+967");
        country2phone.put("ZM", "+260");
        country2phone.put("ZW", "+263");
        country2phone.put("GE", "+995");
        country2phone.put("TW", "+886");
        country2phone.put("AZ", "+374-97");
        country2phone.put("CY", "+90-392");
        country2phone.put("MD", "+373-533");
        country2phone.put("SO", "+252");
        country2phone.put("GE", "+995");
        country2phone.put("CX", "+61");
        country2phone.put("CC", "+61");
        country2phone.put("NF", "+672");
        country2phone.put("NC", "+687");
        country2phone.put("PF", "+689");
        country2phone.put("YT", "+262");
        country2phone.put("GP", "+590");
        country2phone.put("GP", "+590");
        country2phone.put("PM", "+508");
        country2phone.put("WF", "+681");
        country2phone.put("CK", "+682");
        country2phone.put("NU", "+683");
        country2phone.put("TK", "+690");
        country2phone.put("GG", "+44");
        country2phone.put("IM", "+44");
        country2phone.put("JE", "+44");
        country2phone.put("AI", "+1-264");
        country2phone.put("BM", "+1-441");
        country2phone.put("IO", "+246");
        country2phone.put("", "+357");
        country2phone.put("VG", "+1-284");
        country2phone.put("KY", "+1-345");
        country2phone.put("FK", "+500");
        country2phone.put("GI", "+350");
        country2phone.put("MS", "+1-664");
        country2phone.put("SH", "+290");
        country2phone.put("TC", "+1-649");
        country2phone.put("MP", "+1-670");
        country2phone.put("PR", "+1-787and1-939");
        country2phone.put("AS", "+1-684");
        country2phone.put("GU", "+1-671");
        country2phone.put("VI", "+1-340");
        country2phone.put("HK", "+852");
        country2phone.put("MO", "+853");
        country2phone.put("FO", "+298");
        country2phone.put("GL", "+299");
        country2phone.put("GF", "+594");
        country2phone.put("GP", "+590");
        country2phone.put("MQ", "+596");
        country2phone.put("RE", "+262");
        country2phone.put("AX", "+358-18");
        country2phone.put("AW", "+297");
        country2phone.put("AN", "+599");
        country2phone.put("SJ", "+47");
        country2phone.put("AC", "+247");
        country2phone.put("TA", "+290");
        country2phone.put("CS", "+381");
        country2phone.put("PS", "+970");
        country2phone.put("EH", "+212");
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity`, you can call the following function to get the contact list in the device.

```
private void getContactList(){

    String ISOPrefix = getCountryISO();

    Cursor phones = getContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

    while (phones.moveToNext()){
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        phone = phone.replace(" ","");
        phone = phone.replace("-","");
        phone = phone.replace("(","");
        phone = phone.replace(")","");

        if (!String.valueOf(phone.charAt(0)).equals("+")) {
            phone = ISOPrefix + phone;
        }

        UserObject mContact = new UserObject("",name, phone);
        contactList.add(mContact);
        getUserDetails(mContact);
    }
}
```

Here you can get the CountryISO from the device.

```
private String getCountryISO(){
    String iso = null;

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso() != null) {
        if (!telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().toString().equals("")) {
            iso = telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().toString();
        }
    }

    return CountryToPhonePrefix.getPhone(iso);
}
```

And here you can search in Firebase Realtime Database who has an account in your app according to your contact list.

```
private void getUserDetails(UserObject mContact) {
    DatabaseReference mUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
    // Only lists the users that have an account in the app into Firebase
    Query query = mUserDB.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(mContact.getPhone());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String uid, name = "", phone = "", email, image;

                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    uid = childSnapshot.getKey().toString();
                    if (childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue() != null) {
                        phone = childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                    }
                    if (childSnapshot.child("name").getValue() != null) {
                        name = childSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    }
                    email = childSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                    image = childSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    UserObject mUser = new UserObject(childSnapshot.getKey(), name, phone);
                    mUser.setImageUrl(image);

                    if (name.equals(phone)) {
                        for (UserObject mContactIterator : contactList) {
                            if (mContactIterator.getPhone().equals(mUser.getPhone())) {
                                mUser.setName(mContactIterator.getName());
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get list of contacts from system first, and then save those into database. 
Decide, what way you shoud store info of your contacts in database (maybe some additional information), and then tweak sample project from database to do so (it saves single messages as node's child)

Comment: I appreciate for your answer and Thanx for replying Alex Shutov....I have saved Phone Number in an ArrayList....but How Should I Compare it with the huge database of Firebase Contacts.....i.e. over Million Contacts....???

Comment: Firebase stores data as json tree - you store users as children of root node and then contacts for each user, not all contacts altogether

Comment: Actually I will Show you My Datatbase tree

Comment: What do you mean by FirebaseContacts? contacts of all users, using that app?

Comment: Actually I Use phone Number as keys to register new user on the database....So How Would i know That who has actually registered from my phone contacts...i hope you got my question S...ir